# The same generated .JAR file is different in different computers

Tags: java, javafx, jar

We have created an internal tool in Java -> Jar. It is created in JavaFX.

The .jar works fine in 9 out of 11 person's computers, but in 2 of them the .jar is in different size. Those 2 people have the window cut smaller for some reason. I will attach the images to show the difference as well.

First, the .jar in working PC (you can clearly see the edges of the .jar and all the fields are clearly visible:

[image: http://imgur.com/ycm6gk6]

Second, the .jar that is broken (I have painted the areas where you can see that the fields/window is being cut, it's just that the things that are in the frame don't fit there for some reason):

[image]

I can provide additional information if required. But currently it just seems that for those 2 computers the fields don't fit in the frame, can it be the difference in java versions or OS?

Edit:
Adding some information about the layouts etc (all the elements are in the grids):

```
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Group root = new Group();

    GridPane grid0 = new GridPane();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1030, 768);
    final GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(5); //The gap properties manage the spacing between the rows and columns.
    grid.setVgap(5); //Vahe iga rea ja veeru vahel pmst.
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(40, 20, 20, 20)); //while the padding property manages the space around the edges of the grid pane. Ehk kogu raami sisu vahe ��rtest.
    //In this example, there are 10 pixels of padding on each side.
    //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true); //N�itab t�pselt joonduse �ra

    GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();
    grid2.setHgap(5); //The gap properties manage the spacing between the rows and columns.
    grid2.setVgap(5); //Vahe iga rea ja veeru vahel pmst.
    grid2.setPadding(new Insets(40, 20, 20, 20)); //while the padding property manages the space around the edges of the grid pane. Ehk kogu raami sisu vahe ��rtest.

    final GridPane grid3 = new GridPane();
    grid3.setHgap(5); //The gap properties manage the spacing between the rows and columns.
    grid3.setVgap(5); //Vahe iga rea ja veeru vahel pmst.
    grid3.setPadding(new Insets(40, 20, 20, 20)); //while the padding property manages the space around the edges of the grid pane. Ehk kogu raami sisu vahe ��rtest.**strong text**
    grid0.add(grid, 0, 0);
    Line joon2 = new Line(0, 0, 0, 800);
    grid0.add(joon2, 1, 0);
    grid0.add(grid2, 2, 0);
    final Line joon3 = new Line(0, 0, 0, 800);
    grid0.add(joon3, 3, 0);
    grid0.add(grid3, 4, 0);
    root.getChildren().

            add(grid0);

    root.getChildren().

            add(menuBar);

    stage.setResizable(false); //Cannot resize the Bit!
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

Comment: Are screen resolutions same on all 11 machines?

Comment: Good comment, it seems that for those that have the problem have resolution 2560 x 1440 (also recommended for them).
But for those that have it working are all less than that. Could you suggest any fix for that? (Because if they switch it lower, it won't fix it).

Comment: Without any details about the layouts used we cannot make any recommendation except wrapping the whole thing in a `ScrollPane`...

Comment: I added some code snippets about the layouts etc, I hope these will provide some useful information, feel free to ask for more. ;)

Comment: My guess is that it's related to high-DPI features in Windows, that automatically scale windows especially on higher resolutions, but I'm not familiar enough with programming around it to write up an answer.

Comment: If you double-checked that all PCs are running the same Java Version (we had examples where JDK updates changed behaviour) you should give @PeterCooperJr. comment a try. Change the DPI-features in Windows and see what happens. Change your Windows scaling from (100% Standard) to e.g. 125%.

Comment: @EerikMuuli, add a plain label with a white-space as title after the -> button and that should work. Or some layouts has feature to add padding to elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses, I managed to figure out the problem!

There were 2 options to fix this:

1. To change windows scaling under "Screen resolution".
2. I removed the hard-coded scene size and let the size be calculated by the size of the elements in the grids, so it would be dynamic for every computer.